# Lifting an $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$-valued map to an $S^{n-1}$-valued map.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and assume that for each $v\in M$, I have a vector $v(m)\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ with some property and this vector is *unique up to multiple*: further, it depends smoothly on $m$. I would like to define a smooth map $F: M\to S^{n-1}$ that sends $m$ to a representative unit vector with the required property. Under which conditions can this be done?

I understand that it is a lifting problem: I want to lift a smooth map $f: M\to\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ to a map $F: M\to S^{n-1}$. If necessary, I can assume that $\mathrm{dim}\, M<n-1$ but I'm not sure if it is sufficient. Then $f(M)$ has "lower dimension" then $n-1$ and I can assume that it aviods a point, but I can hardly assume that it aviods the whole $\mathbb{RP}^{n-2}$ (in which case I could define a global section on $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}\setminus\mathbb{RP}^{n-2}\to S^{n-1}$)..

Any hint please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem's all in $\pi_1$. Consider the identity map from $\mathbb {RP}^2$ to itself; does this lift to a map to $S^2$? No. Why not? Because at the level of $\pi_1$, it's the identity map. Since $\pi_1(S^2)$ is trivial, the nontrivial identity map on $\mathbb Z / \mathbb {2Z}$ cannot factor through it.

What if (in your question) the map from $\pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(\mathbb {RP}^n)$ is trivial? Then the homotopy lifting property tells you that the map you're looking for exists.

Comment: I forgot to mention something: my whole answer depends on $M$ being path connected, so that $\pi_1$ doesn't depend on basepoint. If it's disconnected, you have to do the $\pi_1$ analysis once per connected component (or path component? not sure...) .

Comment: Your answer is neat and clear, but.. Can I use any of the following to lift it? $M$ is a neat submanifold of $X\times [0,1]$, $X$ is a compact smooth manifold, $\mathrm{dim} M < n-1$, $X$ and $M$ are oriented, $M$ has a framing of the $n$-dimensional normal bundle (in $X\times [0,1]$) and there is a submersion $\pi:Neigh(M)\to X$, $\pi|_M$ is an embedding. $d\pi$ takes exactly one normal vector--**up to multiple**--in each $m$ to the tangent space of $\pi(M)$. Can I use anything of this to get a smooth nowhere zero vector field of these normal vectors on $M$? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'll have to look at this more closely, and don't have time right now. But let me ask: is "neat" a technical term? I don't know it. Also: $d\pi$ takes $X \times [0, 1]$ to $X$; I don't understand what it means to say "$d\pi$ takes exactly one normal vector -up to multiple -- in each $m$ (what's $m$???) to the tangent space of $\pi(M)$". (By looking at my profile, you can probably work out my email address, and we can carry out further discussion by email if you like.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. I will write you a message tomorrow and really appreciate it.